# Show data from JSON in UITableView

Tags: mysql, json, swift, xcode, uitableview

....................................................................................................................................................................
I get the data and print it. Maybe the code is not correct I'm just new into swift, but I don't have any errors in Xcode. There's something missing but I just don't know what.
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    struct Class: Codable {

        let first_name: String
        let last_name: String
        let email: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case first_name = "first_name"
            case last_name = "last_name"
            case email = "email"
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://x.de/x.php")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { print(error!); return }

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let classes = try! decoder.decode([Class].self, from: data)



            for myClass in classes {
                print(myClass.first_name)
                print(myClass.last_name)
                print(myClass.email)
            }

        }
            ).resume()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableview.reloadData()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //return myarray.count
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues

---

- Your view controller is missing dataSource, an Array that holds list of users
- Update the array (dataSource) once remote data is received
- Reload `UITableView` once the array (dataSource) changes, using `tableView.reloadData()`
- Within `numberOfRowsInSection` return the number of array elements `dataSource.count`
- `UITableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` requires that you register a cell class or xib using `tableview.register` method
- Lastly, instead of underscores, as first_name, use camelCase variable naming convention, as firstName

---

```
struct User: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let email: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case email = "email"
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    private var dataSource = [User]() {
        didSet {
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "groupCell")
        self.tableview.dataSource = self
        self.tableview.delegate = self

        let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/users.php")

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "An error occurred")
                return
            }

            // Within `dataTask` we are on background thread, we must update our UITableView on main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.dataSource = try! JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)
            }
        }).resume()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableview.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath)
        let user = self.dataSource[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = user.firstName
        return cell
    }

}
```

Above code yields

[image]

Comment: I have only one error which is: Use of unresolved identifier 'User' @AamirR

Comment: Copy `struct User: Codable { ... }` from my answer above, should resolve the issue

Comment: Well, thanks that worked I should have seen that, sorry. When I start the app it crashes and I got an error: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" where the code is: override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        tableview.reloadData()
    } @AamirR

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and help, it works now :). I edited my url in your answer so no one will be able to see it. Only one question, I tried to show firstName, lastName and email but couldn't, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

In the cellForRowAt func you have to do something like that :

```
cell.textLabel?.text = myarray[indexPath.row]
```

because the text of myarray should be displayed at a label or whatever

Comment: "myarray" what should I write there from my code? @Dennis Feldbusch